# How to Convolute Image using WriteableBitmapEx

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, writeablebitmapex

I would like use WriteableBitmapEx to convolute an image. In my implementation I am receiving an image but I cannot tell any difference.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public WriteableBitmap Process(WriteableBitmap input)
    {
        WriteableBitmap finalbmp = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(input, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelSharpen3x3);
        return finalbmp;
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried any other predefined filter, or have you tried your own designed filter? Can't you see any difference regardless of filter applied?

Comment: I think the issue is that `Process` is called within a background operation, and apparenlty WriteableBitmaps can't be used in a background thread. I have to use the image pixels to perform image processing, but this greatly reduces some of the effects I was hoping to use. Do you know of any resource that would allow me to create interesting effects by modifying the argb values of image pixels?